# Stagefright architecture

Tags: android, stagefright

Is there a documentation explaining android Stagefright architecture?

Can I get some pointers on these subjects?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A good explanation of stagefright is provided at http://freepine.blogspot.com/2010/01/overview-of-stagefrighter-player.html.

There is a new playback engine implemented by Google comes with Android 2.0 (i.e, Stagefright), which seems to be quite simple and straightforward compared with the OpenCORE solution.

- MediaExtractor is responsible for retrieving track data and the corresponding meta data from the underlying file system or http stream;
- Leveraging OMX for decoding: there are two OMX plugins currently, adapting to PV's software codec and vendor's hardware implementation respectively. And there is a local implementation of software codecs which encapsulates PV's decoder APIs directly;
- AudioPlayer is responsible for rendering audio, it also provides the timebase for timing and A/V synchronization whenever audio track is present;
- Depending on which codec is picked, a local or remote render will be created for video rendering; and system clock is used as the timebase for video only playback;
- AwesomePlayer works as the engine to coordinate the above modules, and is finally connected into android media framework through the adapter of StagefrightPlayer.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Look at this [post](http://freepine.blogspot.com/2010/01/overview-of-stagefrighter-player.html).

Also, Android player is built up using PacketVideo (PV) Player, and here comes the docs about it (beware of really slow transfer speed :) ):

- PVPlayer SDK Developer's Guide [link 1](http://blogimg.chinaunix.net/blog/upfile2/101220161541.pdf), [link 2](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/donut/external/opencore/doc/pvplayer_developers_guide.pdf)
- PVPlayer return codes [link](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/external/opencore/doc/pvmf_return_codes.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Starting Gingerbread, it is Stagefright framework instead of PV framework. Above link has good info about the framework. If you have some specific questions, I may be able to help you out.

Thanks, Dolphin

Comment: I want to play .ts files in Android.I am not getting any way to play it.Please help me.

Comment: Which android version you are on?

Comment: I am using ICS.Now I am able to play .ts files.